# Efficient allocation of cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, cell-array

I have some which converts a cell array of strings into a cell array of characters.

Note. For a number of reasons, both the input (C) and the output (C_itemised) must be cell arrays.

The cell array of strings (C) is as follows:

```
>> C(1:10)

ans = 

't1416933446'
''
't1416933446'
''
't1416933446'
''
't1416933446'
''
't1416933446'
''
```

I have only shown a portion of the array here. In reality it is ~28,000 rows in length.

I have some code which does this, although it is very inefficient. The cellstr function takes up 72% of the code's time, as it is currently called thousands of times. The code is as follows:

```
C_itemised=cell(length(C),500);
for i=3:length(C)
    temp=char(C{i});

    for j=1:length(temp)
        C(i-2,j)=cellstr(temp(j));
    end
end
```

I have a feeling that some minor modifications could take out the inner loop, thus cutting down the overall running time substantially. I have tried a number of ways to do this, but I think I keep getting confused about whether to use {} or (), and haven't been able to find anything online that can help me. Can anyone see a way to make the code more efficient?

Please also note that this function is used in conjunction with other functions, and does work, although it is running slower than would be ideal. Therefore, I do not wish to change the format of `C_itemised`.

EDIT:
(A sample of) the output of my current function is:

```
C_itemised(1,1:12)

ans = 

Columns 1 through 12

't'    '1'    '4'    '1'    '6'    '9'    '3'    '3'    '4'    '4'    '6'    []
```

Comment: So you have a cell array of strings.  Is it your goal to take each string, and convert it into a cell array of characters, where each element in this cell array is one individual character?

Comment: Yes, with each row containing the individual characters of the same row in the original array

Answer (score 3):

One thing I can suggest is to use the undocumented function [`sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function/#sprintfc).  This function is hidden from normal use in MATLAB, but it is used internally with a variety of other functions. Mainly, if you tried doing `help sprintfc`, it'll say that there's no function found!  It's cool to sniff around the source sometimes!

How `sprintfc` works is that you provide it a formatting string, much like `printf`, and the data you want printed.  It will take each individual element in the data and place them into individual cell arrays.  As an example, supposing I had a string `D = 'abcdefg';`, if we did:

```
out = sprintfc('%c', D);
```

We get:

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

a


out{2} =

b


out{3} =

c


out{4} =

d


out{5} =

e


out{6} =

f


out{7} =

g
```

As such, it takes each element in your string and places them as individual characters serving as individual elements in a new cell array.  The `%c` formatting string means that we want to print a single character per element.  Check out the link to Undocumented MATLAB that I posted above if you want to learn more!

---

Therefore, try simplifying your loop to this:

```
C_itemised=cell(length(C));
for i=1:length(C)
    C_itemised{i} = sprintfc('%c', C{i});
end
```

`C_itemised` will be a cell array, where each element `C_itemised{i}` is another cell array, with each element in this cell array being a single character that is composed of the string `C{i}`.

---

## Minor Note

You said you were confused about `{}` and `()` in MATLAB for cells.  `{}` is used to access individual elements inside the cell.  So doing `C{1}` for example will grab whatever is stored in the first element of the cell array.  `()` is used to **slice** and index into the cells.  For example, if you wanted to make another cell array that is a subset of the current one, you would do something like `C(1:3)`.  This will create a three element cell array which is composed of the first three cells in `C`.

Comment: This code looks good, although I am currently running out of memory when running it.

Comment: @Doragan - How many characters are per string?  If you have on average around 1000 characters per string, and you have 28000 rows, then you will probably run out of memory quickly.  That doesn't explain why your other code works though.  Try doing a `clear all;` before running your code again?  Also, if you don't intend on using `C` again, consider `null`ing each entry inside the loop, so do `C{i} = [];` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Cool function! Saving that for later.

Comment: @rayryeng the number of characters is generally about 40. I was confused as to why I was running out of memory too, and tried using it on a single row, but had the same problem, so it doesn't seem to be because of the large C array. I also tried restarting Matlab. I will retry the code tomorrow after restarting the machine and will let you know. The sprintfc function looks really useful though.

Comment: @Doragan - That's odd... ok!  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: @rayryeng Still no joy. I have added additional information to my original question, though, as I noticed it was different from the output I got from your function. The output from your function only filled the first element of each row with the whole string. I am attempting to alter it to get it to suit my needs.

Comment: @rayryeng I have changed your example to C_itemised{i,1:length(C(i))} = sprintfc('%c', C{i}); which seems to give the correct output, but still runs into memory problems. The work continues...

Comment: @Doragan - OK, I had a slight misunderstanding with what you wanted.  You actually want a 2D cell array, and that modification you made should work.... but the memory problems is what I'm confused about.  Can you set a breakpoint and check the memory of `C_itemised` at each iteration?